# Чтение словаря в Python

Tags: python

Как можно прочитать словарь с клавиатуры , не зная длины данного словаря (Желательно способ покороче)

Comment: `print(*[ [k, v] for k, v in {'key1': 'vak1','key2': 'vak2','key3': 'vak3',}.items() ], sep='\n')`

Comment: @S.Nick ТС хочет с "клавятуры" прочитать, а Вы ему зачем-то вывод даёте...

Comment: @DefaulDima Как Вы собираетесь отличать конец ввода?

Answer (score 1):

Вот самый простой способ. Соответственно мы должны определить когда кончается ввод.

1. Ввод значений по очереди. Конец ввода `#:#`

   ```
   my_dict={}    
   state=1
   while state!=0:
       print("Введите значение для словаря в формате key:value (для завершения #:#) ")
       key,value=input().split(":")
       if key=="#" and value=="#":
           state=0
       else:
           my_dict[key]=value
    print(my_dict)
   ```
2. Ввод строки вида key1:value1 key2:value2 key3:value3 ...

   ```
    lst=input().split()
    my_dict={}
    for x in lst:
       s=x.split(":")
       my_dict[s[0]]=s[1]

    print(my_dict)
   ```
3. Ввод из файла. В фале пары key:value

   ```
   filer=open("in.txt","r")
   my_dict={}
   for line in filer:
       s=line.split(":")
       my_dict[s[0]]=s[1][:-1]

   print(my_dict)
   ```

`s[1][:-1]` Это мы отрезаем последний символ - символ конца строки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: @defauldima если вас все устраивает, можно пометить ответ как принятый.